# Transform csr_matrix into networkx graph

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, networkx

I have a 1000x1000 sparse matrix (called ppm) in csr_matrix, with 39,000 nonzero elements. It is a symmetric matrix, so I want to transfrm it into a networkx undirected graph with weights.

If I use the constructor directly, it takes 20.8 seconds to create this graph 10 times:

```
g = nx.Graph(ppm)
```

If I use the following code, it will take 9.1 seconds to create this graph 10 times:

```
nr_persons = ppm.shape[0]
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(range(nr_persons))

for i in range(nr_persons):
    for j in ppm.indices[ppm.indptr[i]:ppm.indptr[i+1]]:
        if i <= j:
            g.add_edge(i,j, weight = ppm[i,j])
```

For my application however, this is too slow, since I want to scale up. Is there another, faster, way to create a graph out of a sparse matrix?

PS. Creation of ppm is done with the following code:

```
N_rows = 1000
N_cols =  100
N_nonzero = 2000
m_rows = np.random.random_integers(0, N_rows-1, N_nonzero)
m_cols = np.random.random_integers(0, N_cols-1, N_nonzero)
m_data = np.random.random_integers(1, 10, N_nonzero)   
pam = csr_matrix( (m_data, (m_rows, m_cols)), shape=(N_rows, N_cols) )
ppm = pam.dot(csr_matrix.transpose(pam))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you skip building the matrix?  Then you could use

```
 G.add_weighted_edges_from(zip(m_cols,m_rows,m_data))
```

If not perhaps you can still use the same method (add_weighted_edges_from) on the matrix data

```
ppm.nonzero()
ppm.data
```

This should be much faster.

Comment: I don't see how to implement the first option, since I have to calculate my matrix from another matrix (the dot product). This is very fast in sparse matrix form, that's why I chose that option.

Comment: So can you use x,y=ppm.nonzero() to get the indices and d=ppm.data to get the data and then feed that into G.add_weighted_edges_from(zip(x,y,d))?

Comment: That's it! Timing goes down from 8.5 to 1.3 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

looks like networkx has it's own functions to construct graphs from matrices, have you tried those? are they faster?

[from_numpy_matrix(A, create_using=None)](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_numpy_matrix.html#networkx.convert_matrix.from_numpy_matrix)

[from_scipy_sparse_matrix(A, create_using=None, edge_attribute='weight')](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_scipy_sparse_matrix.html#networkx.convert_matrix.from_scipy_sparse_matrix)

Comment: I didn't try it, but I did now. It is as slow as using the default constructor.

Comment: sorry I couldn't be of much help. but why do you have to use a sparse matrix? wouldn't an edge list be more efficient?